# how to convert non-stable sorting to stable algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I searched for it too much but I could not find noting well.

suggest an algorithm to make all non-stable sorting algorithms to work as stable sorting algorithms?

Comment: There is a big table of sort algorithms in the Wikipedia entry for sorting.  It indicates which are stable and which are not stable.  Have you thought about doing some homework before you ask on stackoverflow?

Comment: Assuming you're using what would normally be a non-stable sort, one option would be to generate a set of indices 0 to n-1 for an array, or a set of pointers for an array. Sort the indices or pointers according to the array, and if equal, compare the indices or pointers to retain the original order.

Comment: not only I am not searching for homework solution but I am giving some questions as homework. I wanna some algorithm not any kind of code. @RexD

Answer (score 1):

Use extra memory to store the original order of the array. Then use that order in the algorithm when comparing two equal elements.

Here's an example of how to make Python's `list.sort` stable:

```py
def make_stable(algorithm):
    def stable_version(A):
        #adding original order of the array
        A2 = [(y, x) for x, y in enumerate(A)]

        #running algorithm in modified array
        algorithm(A2)

        #replacing original array with the result only
        A[:] = [y for y, x in A2]

    return stable_version

A = [3, 2, 1, 2]
stable_sort = make_stable(list.sort)
stable_sort(A)
print A
```

Comment: I think there is something wrong here !
i try to describe it better for @Rex. read it please

Comment: That is a correct answer. Basically you make 2-tuples and sort them, if first elements of tuples are equal then second are compared. After all you just throw away second elements.

Comment: Python's sort correctly sorts tuples.  It is also a stable sort, which is something different.  If you want to correctly sort tuples in general, you can first sort on the secondary key, then use a stable sort on the primary key.  This was all worked out in the 1960s if not earlier.

Comment: The *"to make Python's list.sort stable"* is misleading, since it already **is** stable, so you can't "make" it stable. (It has been stable [since Python 2.2](https://docs.python.org/2.7/howto/sorting.html#sort-stability-and-complex-sorts), released in 2001, well before your answer).

Answer (score 0):

Well, here's another approach which works for integers and strings:

- int: **key -> n * key + index**
- str: **key -> right_padded(key) + padded(n * len(key) + index)**

To test it, I've made list.sort unstable by first reversing the array.

```py
from collections.abc import Callable
from math import ceil, log10
from typing import Any

DEBUG: bool = True


def unstable_sort(arr: list[tuple[int, Any]]) -> None:
    arr.reverse()
    arr.sort(key=lambda item: item[0])


def stable_sort_integers(
    arr: list[tuple[int, Any]],
    sort: Callable[[list[tuple[int, Any]]], None] = unstable_sort
) -> None:
    if len(arr) <= 1:
        return arr

    if DEBUG:
        arr_1: list[tuple[int, Any]] = arr.copy()
        sort(arr_1)
        print(f'Normal        : {arr_1}')

    n: int = len(arr)
    for i, (key, value) in enumerate(arr):
        arr[i] = n * key + i, value

    sort(arr)
    for i, (key, value) in enumerate(arr):
        arr[i] = key // n, value

    if DEBUG:
        print(f'Using indexing: {arr}')

def stable_sort_strings(
    arr: list[tuple[str, Any]],
    sort: Callable[[list[tuple[str, Any]]], None] = unstable_sort
) -> None:
    if len(arr) <= 1:
        return arr

    if DEBUG:
        arr_1: list[tuple[str, Any]] = arr.copy()
        sort(arr_1)
        print(f'Normal        : {arr_1}')

    n: int = len(arr)
    key_length: int = max(len(item[0]) for item in arr)
    index_length: int = ceil(log10(n * key_length + n))
    for i, (key, value) in enumerate(arr):
        arr[i] = (
            f'{key:<{key_length}}{n * len(key) + i:0{index_length}d}', value
        )

    sort(arr)
    for i, (key, value) in enumerate(arr):
        arr[i] = (
            key[:-index_length + int(key[-index_length:]) // n - key_length],
            value
        )

    if DEBUG:
        print(f'Using indexing: {arr}')

stable_sort_integers([
    (2, 'one  '),
    (1, 'two  '),
    (1, 'three')
])
stable_sort_strings([
    ('b', 'one  '),
    ('a', 'two  '),
    ('a', 'three')
])
```

Ouput:

```
Normal        : [(1, 'three'), (1, 'two  '), (2, 'one  ')]
Using indexing: [(1, 'two  '), (1, 'three'), (2, 'one  ')]
Normal        : [('a', 'three'), ('a', 'two  '), ('b', 'one  ')]
Using indexing: [('a', 'two  '), ('a', 'three'), ('b', 'one  ')]
```

Answer (score -3):

There are stable sorting algorithms and unstable sorting algorithms.
You should just select a stable algorithm.
Arrays.sort in Java is required to be stable.

Comment: I think we can do this with some changes on equal numbers. some changes like adding a very small number to equal numbers